# Android: Add text to a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, image-editing

Is there a way to add text to a bitmap with rotation and text customization, and them save the bitmap with text to the device storage. Also can this be applied to adding images to an image?

Comment: this is "image processing", it's too broad to explain, you should study how to manipulate Bitmaps or search for a library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a Canvas backed up by a Bitmap with `new Canvas(myMutableBitmap)` and do your text drawing in it. Then save the bitmap back with `myMutableBitmap.compress()`.